# Recursive functions doesn't appear to return value

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have a recursive function that I want to return an object from an array of objects. Each object in the array contains a reference to a "neighboring" object, like this:

```
{
  id: 5,
  neighbors: {
    north: 1,
    east: 6,
    south: 9,
    west: 4
  }
}
```

For those playing along this is the 5 square on a 4x4 board.

The function takes the array of all the board squares, the id of the current square, and a direction:

```
function findFarthestEmpty(board, id, direction) {
  let nextSquare = board[id].neighbors[direction]
  if (nextSquare === null) {
    console.log('return last square on board', board[id])
    return board[id]
  } else {
    findFarthestEmpty(board, nextSquare, direction)
  }
}
//Try a move.
console.log(typeof(findFarthestEmpty(board, 5, 'north')))
```

When I run the function as seen above, I get the proper square object logging from line 4, but my statement is "undefined." Perhaps I'm confusing statements and expressions?

If you want the board array:

```
let board = [ { id: 0,
neighbors: { north: null, east: 1, south: 4, west: null },
meeple: null },
{ id: 1,
neighbors: { north: null, east: 2, south: 5, west: 0 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 2,
neighbors: { north: null, east: 3, south: 6, west: 1 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 3,
neighbors: { north: null, east: null, south: 7, west: 2 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 4,
neighbors: { north: 0, east: 5, south: 8, west: null },
meeple: null },
{ id: 5,
neighbors: { north: 1, east: 6, south: 9, west: 4 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 6,
neighbors: { north: 2, east: 7, south: 10, west: 5 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 7,
neighbors: { north: 3, east: null, south: 11, west: 6 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 8,
neighbors: { north: 4, east: 9, south: 12, west: null },
meeple: null },
{ id: 9,
neighbors: { north: 5, east: 10, south: 13, west: 8 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 10,
neighbors: { north: 6, east: 11, south: 14, west: 9 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 11,
neighbors: { north: 7, east: null, south: 15, west: 10 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 12,
neighbors: { north: 8, east: 13, south: null, west: null },
meeple: null },
{ id: 13,
neighbors: { north: 9, east: 14, south: null, west: 12 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 14,
neighbors: { north: 10, east: 15, south: null, west: 13 },
meeple: null },
{ id: 15,
neighbors: { north: 11, east: null, south: null, west: 14 },
meeple: null } ]
```

Comment: Consider what your function is returning when `nextSquare` _isn't_ `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting undefined because of this:

```
typeof(findFarthestEmpty(board, 5, 'north'))
```

The recursive function isn't returning anything at this moment.
When you are at your base case you return the id but it only returns to the recursive statement. You need to add a return to the recursive case, so that the recursive case also returns the answer:

```
else {
   return findFarthestEmpty(board, nextSquare, direction)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 7 return that function. It will work as expected